# Keyboard shortcut in google spreadsheet for switching between search results

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I do a lot of searching in google spreadsheets. I use command f (I'm on a mac) to find the search results, and would love to be able to go down the search results list using keyboard shortcuts. To clarify, I'm looking for a way to go down the list of my matches from my search word by pressing a key on my keyboard. I want to be able to see a result and then move down the list to see another result. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

after you invoke search box try pressing <kbd>**Enter**</kbd>

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear with my question. I'm trying to scroll through my search result with a keyboard shortcut. I have no issues searching the google doc, it's going through the response that I need to do (without my mouse).